# Why are (most) right hand dominant people also right foot dominant? And the same for left handed/footed people

Tags: physiology, development

Just as the title states -- Why do people who are right hand dominant also tend to be right foot dominant? And, the same question for left handed/footed people.

Does the brain actually designate an *entire side* of the body to use by default, when only one hand/arm/leg/foot/eye/ear is needed, or available?

Comment: Is there actually such a thing as a dominant foot?  Certainly seems as though I use either foot equally, depending on the direction of whatever I'm doing.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, I believe there is such a thing..if you were to kick a ball, which foot would you choose to use? Obviously not both.. in my question, I did mention, *"..when only **one** hand/arm/leg/foot/..*", so, tasks where one side of the body *isn't* favored, shouldn't be considered.

Comment: Actually I'd use whichever foot was closer to the ball - or if it's a soccer ball, both feet alternately.

Comment: @jamesqf *"Over 90% of right-handers are also right-footers; right-footedness hence predominates in the general population."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footedness

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe I'm the oddball here, though it's perhaps not surprising, since I'm fairly ambidexterous (or perhaps ambi-clumsy would be closer to the truth).  I can do most things adequately well with either hand.  Though the right is better for most, some things, like baseball batting, I do better left-handed.